# convert links from html page to json format in python

Tags: python, json, parsing, html-parser

I have an HTML page and I want to get the links from this [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAbIL.png) and then convert them into JSON format. This is the link to search[page](https://www.google.com/search?q=mobile%20proxies&oq=mobile%20proxies&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l5j69i61l2.2911j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Here is what I have tried.

```
class HtmltoJsonParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self,raise_exception = True): 
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        #self.reset()
        self.doc = {}
        self.path = [] 
        self.cur = self.doc
        self.line = 0
        self.raise_exception = raise_exception
        
    @property
    def json(self):
        return self.doc
   
    @staticmethod
    def to_json(content, raise_exception = True):
        parser = HtmltoJsonParser(raise_exception = raise_exception)
        parser.feed(content)
        return parser.json
    
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        # Only parse the 'anchor' tag.
        if tag == "a":
            for name,link in attrs:
                if name == "href" and link.startswith("http"):
                    self.cur["" +name]= link
                    #print (link)
```

I took the help from this [blog](http://www.xavierdupre.fr/blog/2013-10-27_nojs.html). I want to get an output like this

```
{
    "ads": [
      {
           "position": 1,
           "link": "https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwitk5Ou2qX6AhVK07IKHdyyCwQYABADGgJscg&ohost=www.google.com&cid=CAASJeRoa3Q-GtJJqeqbQ0EjhhL22QNYj4Sg_79Man_cWa0tjzSi8Ho&sig=AOD64_3-qhJH4tfcxt1VMfxwOTF8BKeFXA&q&adurl&ved=2ahUKEwikz4uu2qX6AhVXAxAIHfwECwoQ0Qx6BAgFEAM",
    },
    {
         "position": 2,
         "link": "https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwitk5Ou2qX6AhVK07IKHdyyCwQYABAAGgJscg&ohost=www.google.com&cid=CAASJeRoa3Q-GtJJqeqbQ0EjhhL22QNYj4Sg_79Man_cWa0tjzSi8Ho&sig=AOD64_1ZUcXQhcCFUYnBHo3jqlckXL2agg&q&adurl&ved=2ahUKEwikz4uu2qX6AhVXAxAIHfwECwoQ0Qx6BAgCEAE",
    }   ] }
```

but Im getting this

{'href': 'https://policies.google.com/terms?hl=en-PL&fg=1'}

Why is it not appending the link to JSON self.cur? I have tried appending it but I got key error every time.

Comment: why not just use beautifulsoup ? Provide the link to the HTML page

Comment: I added the link https://www.google.com/search?q=mobile+proxies&oq=mobile+proxies&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l5j69i61l2.2911j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @imtrappedman I don't want to work with links but downloaded google search pages and with classes.

Comment: use beautifulsoup. you want to get links from the search query ? share the code you are using to get the pages.

Comment: I don't have the code for downloading pages. and beautifulsoup will help me to get the lnks then how to add them as json object

Comment: ok, you want to get all the result links that showup when you search `mobile proxies` right ?

Comment: NO only the link links like in above search with heading "Buy Mobile proxies -Bright data.." then "Buy Mobile proxies" and so on

Comment: ok. i got it and do you have to use this class ? why not just use beautifulsoup. you dont have code to download the webpage then how are you using the class

Comment: I am willing to use beautifulsoup but it must be within a class function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is here

```
self.cur["" +name]= link
```

as `name=='href'` is true, this will always update the value stored at `name` and not append it. try this.

```
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        # Only parse the 'anchor' tag.
        if tag == "a":
            for name, link in attrs:
                print(attrs)
                if name == "href" and link.startswith("http"):
                    cur = {}
                    cur["position"]= self.line
                    self.line += 1
                    cur["link"] = link 
                    self.doc["ads"].append(cur)
                    #print (link)
```

but with what you have mentioned you should change `link.startswith("http")` to `link.startswith("/url?q=")`

Comment: I got an error with this KeyError: 'ads'

Comment: change `self.doc = {}` to `self.doc = {"ads" : [] }`

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot its working. just one thing why my position is starting from '34' and I want to assign the word "top" to all the first large links

Comment: I have used `self.line` to keep track of position. make sure it is not being updates anywhere else. create a new variable in case it is.

Comment: "I want to assign the word "top" to all the first large links" this is not clear

Comment: Nothing I got it. Thanks a lot I wish I had your contact :) It was really helpful. Three Cheers

Comment: @snoozy why not ? what do you want discord ? whatsapp ?

Comment: yeah that would be great :)

Comment: ok send me your discord tag.